# Doubts regarding Server side session using caching or cookie based sessions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, server-side, session-cookies, flask

I am pretty new to web development. I am working with Flask, Sqlalchemy and Postgresql.

As far as I have understood, every new request is like a new thread of the program. New sqlalchemy session is created using which we manage our db operations and return a response. After that new thread is also closed and connections returned to the pool.

I login a user and get all user data in an user orm object. I stored it in flask session variable which uses cookie. Now I also want to save some other user related data for the span of whole user session not a request. I have doubts storing all that data in a cookie for 2 reasons:

```
1. Unnecessary data travel back and forth.
2. data can be read easily.
```

Are my doubts valid?

So my other questions are :

1. Am I right on some level to avoid getting some session wide data in each request without getting into the trap of premature optimization?
   or
   Should I worry about this later when need arises and right now concentrate only on creating a working app?
2. Alternative to cookie based session is server side session which can be done by using redis or memcache. Where does Beaker library comes into this? Is it a standalone thing or to be used in conjunction with redis or memcache?

Comment: beaker is the python wrapper for memcached. it also supports server side sessions, so just use beaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most browsers support cookies of up to 4096 bytes. ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx))

If you want to save more than this than you should use a server-side session backend like Redis or Memcache. It's very easy to replace the default cookie session interface of Flask with a Redis or Memcache interface. There is a [great snippet for redis](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/) by Armin. If you prefere memcache than you can replace the redis stuff of the snippet with the same memcache methods. ;)